# Mathematical function for the powers

Tags: notation, exponentiation, tetration

I have this formula $$\underbrace{2^{2^{2^{.^{.^{.^{2^2}}}}}}}_n$$i.e. where the total number of 2's is $n$.

Is there any way to write it as a single mathematical function?

Comment: You might want to ask this in the [Tetration Forum](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/index.php)

Comment: FWIW, repeated exponentiation is called [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Comment: I know it as the *tower* function/operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knuth invented a notation for these kinds of expressions, called "[up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation#Introduction)".

To express the power tower in your question with up-arrow notation, we can simply write $2\uparrow\uparrow n$.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I needed

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation). In your case, $2\uparrow\uparrow n$.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Definition)  you can  define this number as :

$$^n2 =
\begin{cases}
 1, & \text{if }n=0 \\
 2^{[^{n-1}2]}, & \text{if }n>0
\end{cases}$$