# What methods are used to look into $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ and other stacked towers of repeating irrational numbers?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I recently saw a YouTube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdHFLfv-ThQ&ab_channel=Stand-upMaths) and it got me thinking, does anyone on this site have any insight on how we would tackle (change to base ten, evaluate, compute, or even put limits on approaching) some things like this?

examples:

> 1. $\displaystyle e^{e^{e^e}}$
> 2. $\displaystyle \pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$
> 3. $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}}$
> 4. $\ln(2)^{\ln(2)^{\ln(2)^{\ln(2)}}}$

What methods are proposed to even look at these things? Would it be a good idea to change to complex for pi? Do all towers of root 2 just simplify to 2?

note: Apologies for being new and not knowing how to format the text correctly.

Edit: Things I am thinking, for

> $$\displaystyle \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{2}} = \sqrt{2}^{2} = 2 $$

This gets me thinking that regardless of the height (greater then 3) of the tower of it will always be 2.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}<\sqrt{2}^2=2$.

Comment: What does "tackle some things like this" mean? Compute it?

Comment: Sorry I am of the understanding that you can not compute pi^pi^pi^pi, it is too large, maybe some of the others we can.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is any known "method" to look at these.

Comment: If there were a widely known method to approach whether any of these were an integer, it would be in the video or a top comment on that video.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [transcendental number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number_theory) as a field that studies this, [Gelfond-Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) as a theorem that at least can tell you $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental, and [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) as something that can at least prove (1) is transcendental. (And maybe some of the others? Unsure). Also, might point out your examples 3 and 4 are, respectively, in $(1,2)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Regarding your Edit: $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}} = 1.840{\dots}$, which is not $2$.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the video you cite asks whether a particular power tower is an integer.  You don't mention any relation between this goal and your phrase "how we would tackle some things like this".  "Tackle" in what sense?

Comment: Good point, I will define what I mean when I say tackle in the original post.

Comment: What do you mean by *solve*, OneCold? It doesn't make any sense to "solve" a number.

Comment: If you are given a question, you give an answer, or a solution, you solve the problem. Is this a comment about me using the word solve when there is no x in the problem? Come on, set the problem to x then there x to solve for? Definition :solve
/sälv/
verb
find an answer to, explanation for, or means of effectively dealing with (a problem or mystery):

Comment: I'm sorry, OneCold, but "solve $e^{e^{e^e}}$" makes no more sense than "solve $17$." In any event, I don't know what it means, and I can't help you if I can't understand your question. What do you actually want to know about $e^{e^{e^e}}$ and those other numbers?

Comment: Seriously? Ok, how about change to the normal base ten we are familiar with looking at numbers as? Is familiar now ambiguity or subjective? I love you math people, I swear that some of you get your kicks telling people they asked their question wrong. Come on. You are telling me there is not way for a reasonable person to interpret the meaning of a question, What are you a computer? No. you are a human, capable of understanding meaning, not a computer. Also if you can't help, then don't, thanks.

Comment: You probably can't change these numbers to base ten, since there's not enough paper/bits in the universe to write the digits. (Though it could be difficult to prove some of these aren't rational!) We can certainly get approximations, but those are inexact in a way which usually isn't what we're after in pure mathematics. The point, I think, isn't "the question is wrong", but "the question isn't precise enough to give useful answers".

Comment: Ok, I give up, Please take the question down. It was not a worth use of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematical function for the powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110826/mathematical-function-for-the-powers)

Comment: @OneColdRuben This is like the $4$th question I've seen about this video lol

Comment: Also this is wrong $ \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{2}} = \sqrt{2}^{2} = 2$

Comment: I'm sad to see you give up, OneCold. You could probably learn something, if you took our comments seriously, instead of trying to fight them. Anyway, I think your emphasis on irrational numbers is misplaced. $e^{e^{e^e}}$ is no harder to "tackle" than is $3.5^{3.5^{3.5^{3.5}}}$, or even $4^{4^{4^4}}$, which is a number with something like $10^{150}$ digits if you could write it out in base ten. I doubt we will ever know, say, the middle digit of that number, and there's no irrationality there.

Comment: As for my insistence on careful phrasing of questions, it's when I see you write $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}}}=\sqrt2^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2}}$ that I recognize, even if you don't, that your sloppiness and carelessness have real consequences and lead you to gross mistakes. If you take a little more care in how you express yourself, you won't make stupid errors like that one.

Comment: So, after you gave up, you got three answers. Do you want to engage with these users who have tried to help you? Have they solved your question? Is there anything you want to ask them to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous, but we could interpret it as one about [computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability) and [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) equality. Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number), $\mathbb{Q}^+$ be the set of positive rational numbers, and $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number). A [computable real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) is a real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) $f_x : \mathbb{Q}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that

$$ |f_x(\varepsilon) - x| \leq \varepsilon $$

That is, $f_x$ is a computer program such that, for any desired rational error tolerance $\varepsilon > 0$, $f_x$ yields a rational number within $\varepsilon$ of $x$. For an implementation of this concept, see [*Toward an API for the real numbers*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3385412.3386037) ([summary](https://blog.acolyer.org/2020/10/02/toward-an-api-for-the-real-numbers)).

Now note that

\begin{align}
a^{a^{a^a}}
&= \exp a^{a^a} \log a \\
&= \exp (\exp a^a \log a) \log a \\
&= \exp (\exp (\exp a \log a) \log a) \log a
\end{align}

So we can reduce any [power tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) to exponentials and logarithms, which are computable. Finally, note that the constants $e, \pi, \sqrt{2}, \ln 2$ are computable. Therefore, all the numbers listed in the question are computable.

In fact, we have something even stronger:

> Can we **decide equality** for recursive reals computed from integer constants by a combination of the following operations, which we will refer to as "calculator operations": (1) the four basic arithmetic operations, and square roots; (2) the sin, cos and tan trigonometric functions and their inverses; and (3) exponential and (natural) logarithm functions.

The answer turns out to be yes, as proven in the 1994 paper [*The identity problem for elementary functions and constants*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/190347.190429). Since $e = \exp 1$ and $\pi = 2 \sin^{-1} 1$, we can decide equality between any of the numbers listed in your question and any given integer. Therefore, we can decide whether any of the numbers listed in your question *is* an integer.

For example, to decide whether $x = \pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ is an integer: Compute an integer upper bound $u \geq x$, say $u = 4^{4^{4^4}}$. Then, for all integers $k \in \{1, \dots, u\}$ (of which there are only finitely many), decide whether $x = k$. If equality holds for any $k$, $x$ is integer-valued. Otherwise, it is not integer-valued.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackExchange. There seems to be quite a few questions that you might be asking. First, using $I$ to represent an irrational number, let's look at converting $I^{I^{I^I}}$ to its decimal representation.

$$
I^{I^{I^I}} = I^{\left(I^{\left(I^I\right)}\right)} 
$$

As with all algebra, we need to work on the inside-most parentheses. Add elements of the [Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) ($I^1 = I)$ or [MacLaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) ($I^0=1$) Series in order until they are smaller than the precision of your desired answer. Repeat as you work your way outwards. This, of course, is a naive implementation, but it will work. Taylor Series for $e^x$ are better known and easier to work with, so let's check that out:

$$
\begin{align*}
e^x &= a^b \\
x &= \ln\left(a^b\right) = b \ln (a)\\
I^I &= e^{I \ln(I)} \text{ giving you more rational factors}\\
I^{\left(I^I\right)} &= e^{e^{I \ln(I)} \ln (I)}\\
I^{\left(I^{\left(I^I\right)}\right)} &= e^{e^{e^{I \ln(I)} \ln (I)}\ln(I)}
\end{align*}
$$

Still, to do a numerical approximation, there's a lot of work to use a Taylor Series. Another option would be to use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) since you know the values at $0$ and $1$ and finding derivatives of the function seems doable. I believe this would be a much faster implementation than the naive Taylor. A more sophisticated Taylor is likely also available in which you find an approximation of the entire beast instead of each step individually. It sounds hard.

Next, can these towers have rational representations? It's possible with probability zero. There are a infinitely more irrational numbers than than rationals. Last, it appears your example with $\sqrt 2$ misunderstands exponentiation. $a^{b^c} = a^{\left(b^c\right)} \neq \left(a^b\right)^c \neq a^{(b\cdot c)}$.